# Works in Oracle or sybase but not in netezza. getting error ERROR: (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting

Tags: netezza, correlated-subquery

My table data is as below.
I have to find the hh_num column just printed the xpected result for the third column as below.

```
row_num rel_no  hh_num
1        0        1
2        6        1
3        8        1
4        0        4
5        0        5
6        0        6
7        2        6
8        3        6
9        6        6
10       0       10
```

I would write a query like below.

Case when rel = 0 hh_num would be same as row_num
but when rel <> 0 then hh_num would be max of row_num with rel = 0 but less than the current row num.

```
UPDATE table1
SET HH_NUM = (SELECT MAX(p.ROW_NUM) FROM table1 p WHERE p.REL = 0 and p.row_num < h.row_num  )
FROM table1 h
WHERE h.HH_NUM = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create temp table table1 (
row_num int
,rel_no int
,hh_num int

);

insert into table1
select 1,        0,        null
union all
select 2,        6,        null
union all
select 3,        8,        null
union all
select 4,        0,        null
union all
select 5,        0,        null
union all
select 6,        0,        null
union all
select 7,        2,        null
union all
select 8,        3,        null
union all
select 9,        6,        null
union all
select 10,       0,       null;   

 update table1 a set hh_num = sub.hh_num
 from
 (select h.rowid as rown, h.row_num, h.rel_no, max(p.row_num) as hh_num
 from table1 h inner join
 table1 p
 on p.rel_no = 0 and p.row_num <h.row_num
 group by h.rowid, h.row_num, h.rel_no) sub
 where a.rowid=sub.rown;

  update table1 set hh_num = row_num
 where rel_no = 0;
```